# How to retrieve data from Excel and add to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-2013

I have a Word template file that retrieves data from an Excel file to populate a form.

The code looks something like this:

```
Dim myXL As Object
Set myXL = Getobject("myfile.xls")
myXL.Application.Visible = True
myXL.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

This code works fine in Office 2010 and 2007, but when I try it in 2013, it gives **`run time error 9`** which is an **`array subscript error`**. When I check the Windows array it has zero elements, so error is correct.

How do I achieve the same result in 2013?

The next bit of code attempts to access the **`Worksheets("mysheet"`**) and if I skip the Visible = True line accessing the worksheet gives **`runtime error 1004.`**

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code work on Office 2013 I added the line myXL.Activate before trying to make the Window visible. So the code becomes:

```
Dim myXL As Object
Set myXL = Getobject("myfile.xls")
myXL.Application.Visible = True
myXL.Activate
myXL.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
```

This fixed the run-time error, and the code went back to working well.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve data from an Excel

An Example would be...

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExcelData()
    Dim xlApp As Object ' Application
    Dim xlBook As Object ' Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Object ' Worksheet
    Dim FilePath As String

    FilePath = "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx"

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set xlSht = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ActiveDocument
        .Content = xlSht.Range("A1").Value
    End With

    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, it's interesting how different it is to the code I'm messing with. The final line to get the sheet in my code is: Set myWS = myXL.Application.Worksheets("Sheet1"), and after that things look similar, though it does a myXL.Quit at the end rather than changing visibility.