# Autofill word with data from excel row. A autofill word document per excel row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, autofill, generate

It is possible to generate a word template from every excel row individually. In excel I need a button to appear on every new row I populate with data and the button must open the word template that was fill with the data that I populate the row. And also i need the autofill word template to be save

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36172605/4539709

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help others achieving a better solution for your problem please share more information about your issue on your post, code snippets or screenshots are the best way to give other supporters a clearer image of what could be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a button on the Excel rows, simply have a cell in which you can enter a character. Then use mailmerge with a filter to process those rows. If you want to automate the merge from:

- Word, see *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files*; or
- Excel, see    *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files*,

in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html